# Website always load twice on start

Tags: plugins, javascript, jquery

[This is the website](https://www.antares-is.de/)
Whenever you open the website it loads first and then disappear for a second and loads again. I don’t know what is causing this issue but it is very annoying.
Any advices what can be the problem?
When you open the website you can see it pop up for a second, disappear and then loads correctly…

I think it is something with JS!
In the Autoptimize Plugin if I merge all JS files into one the problem is gone but my website looks very terrible, so I do not activate that function.
Anyway it’s not the problem of plugins because if I deactivate them, nothing change, so I guess it’s something with JS...

This is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function
    at autoptimize_single_faaaa3934096c19bf703ada62e5c7bbc.js:56
    at autoptimize_single_faaaa3934096c19bf703ada62e5c7bbc.js:58
```

Comment: Please disable autoptimize and let us know.

Comment: I tried but still the problem. But if I inline all JS and merge them the loading problem is fixed but then my website looks like a mess as nothing works anymore...